# Combined document - wrong password

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign to sign some documents in a single envelope.

I have used a java library (docusign-restclient) to send the signing request and I am trying to get the signed document using the same java library.
Unfortunately the call does not work.

I have been able to replicate the same error using the demo site and its API explorer: http://iodocs.docusign.com/

To get the signed document I execute:

```
{
  "uri": "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/487325/envelopes/d550e6ca-e776-49c6-8722-dba77174fc83/documents/combined?show_changes=&watermark=&certificate=",
  "headers": {
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication": "{\"Username\":\"xxxxx@gmail.com\",\"Password\":\"xxxxx\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"ALTI-xxxc12d2-3321-45eb-b39c-886fd01d25aa\"}"
  }
}
```

The same credentials works for all the other API calls, but this call returns always the same error:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "content-length": "72",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "date": "Thu, 22 May 2014 20:56:58 GMT",
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=7776000; includeSubDomains"
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",
  "message": "wrong password"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ***wrong password*** error message seems odd to me -- the only password you're specifying in the request is the one in the **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header, and if that password is incorrect, the error response should contain this error info:

```
{
  "errorCode": "USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
  "message": "One or both of Username and Password are invalid."
}
```

FWIW, I'm unable to reproduce the error that you describe.  I can successfully execute the "**GET Documents**" request both via POSTMAN and via DocuSign's IODOCS tool (http://iodocs.docusign.com/).

```
GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/######/envelopes/9210EF93-7733-4A83-86D6-3A53098CFDB9/documents/combined?show_changes=&watermark=&certificate= 
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"xxxxxx@gmail.com","Password":"xxxxxx!","IntegratorKey":"XXXX-eae5f282-f3j5-47c3-b293-1c4cf55b74rt"}
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
```

The response to this request contains the byte stream for the document(s) in the specified Envelope.  Since this call works for me, I'd think you could safely rule out an issue with the operation and/or DocuSign service, and instead focus on closely examining the data you're sending across the wire, and also make sure that the specified member account (i.e., corresponding to credentials in **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header) has access to the specified envelope, etc.

For troubleshooting purposes, I'd also suggest that you try this same operation (via IODOCS is fine) for a different Envelope.  If it works for a different Envelope, then you've narrowed it down to something with the first Envelope that's causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is caused by encryption applied to the document: it is a protected pdf.
I was not expecting issues because DocuSign can open the document and it can modify it. The signed document is sent to my email address.

It always fails when I use this protected pdf but it works with other documents.

Thanks

Comment: That's really interesting, since I'd expect DocuSign to have trouble with a password-protected file upon import (i.e., during Sending) -- because it wouldn't be able to read the file in order to store it in the DocuSign system.  Once a file has been successfully imported into the DocuSign system (i.e., added to an Envelope), there's no concept of a 'password-protected' document -- so I'm not clear on why you'd ever get the 'wrong password' error when simply trying to request Envelope documents from DocuSign.

Comment: Document is protected just to block some functionality.
It is still possible to read it without providing a password. Other functionality like copy are disabled. 
I am sure that the PDF I sent was protected and the signing process worked. 
There seems to be only a problem when it tries to retrieve the combined document: in this case, it seems that the code is doing something wrong.

Comment: I tried to use the same pdf sending the envelope from the DocuSign site instead of using the java library.
As you (Kim Brandl) expected the process fails immediately.
So... why it works using the Java API??

Comment: All I can assume is that the code path (in DocuSign) must be different for a file during import when it's added via API than when it's added via the DocuSign web console.  In general though, you can expect DocuSign to (eventually, at some point) have trouble processing files that are 'protected' or 'encrypted' in any way -- best practise would be to only add unprotected/unencrypted files to Envelopes.  (Once they're in the DocuSign system, files are of course stored in a secure fashion -- hashed/encrypted, etc.)

Comment: The document was protected but with an empty user password. Only the owner password was set to modify access permissions.
Such a document can be easily opened and saved using a java library removing the owner password and all the associated restrictions.